# Spring Security 3 X-XSS-Protection HTTP header not working

Tags: spring-security, http-headers, xss

I have a default Spring login form which accepts a username and password.

I tried setting the security response headers in the security XML as follows:

```
<security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:form-login default-target-url="/home.jsp" always-use-default-target='true'/>
    <security:headers/>
<security:http/>
```

The headers are getting added in the response which I can see when I inspect the page. But when I put a script tag `<script>alert('1')</script>`in the username field and login the form, the script gets executed. Ideally this script should not execute because the X-XSS-Protection header is added in the response.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use a browser that supports this header?

Comment: Yes, I checked this on Internet Explorer 8+ and Chrome. It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this header as a prevention method is not recommended. I don't personally know the ins and outs of Spring Security, but my advice is to follow the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

The XSS filter in IE 8 and newer, does not [properly guard against stored XSS](http://blog.whitehatsec.com/internet-explorer-xss-filter/). Really this is just a filter put in place by Microsoft to protect users against inadequate protection offered by some websites. The websites themselves should properly secure their pages by encoding output and not rely on filters like these.

It is also possible to [turn the XSS against itself](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/security-gone-awry-ie-8-xss-filter-exposes-sites-to-xss-attacks/6221) and make a previously XSS secure site vulnerable, which is another reason you should actually send the header to disable the filter rather than the other way round.